# Interactive Services Detection windows not responsive

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows-server-2016

I am getting the standard Interactive Services Detection message, click on 'View the message' and get to see the desired screen:

[image: interactive services detection message]

Inside there, nothing is responding to either mouse or keyboard. Not even the 'Return now' message from the interactive services themselves:

[image: irresponsive screen]

The screen gets completely stuck, and the only way to release it is to either resize the remote desktop display, or log in again.

We are using this feature in many other environments, and this is the first time we encounter it.

My user is in the administrators user group, and the same behavior is experienced even when logging in with the administrator user.

System:
Windows Server 2016 Standard
Adobe Photoshop CC2017

Any clue will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm surprised Adobe hasn't fixed this yet. The ISD service was implemented in Vista as a non-permanent workaround to deal with the newly introduced [Session 0 isolation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/). Going forward, application vendors were supposed to update their code to avoid interacting with Session 0.

Comment: As a general rule, we keep the ISD service stopped. Sometimes it is needed, though, when Photoshop throws notices that need to be dealt with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out that in Windows Server 2016 the "by design" behavior of the interactive services is to be... well... non-interactive.

This means that keyboard and mouse interaction is disabled, so you need to run any Photoshop job that you have in a real-world window, disable any pop-ups, and only then will you be able to have a successful session.

Just to add after some months of experience: in order to release the license agreement, we found out that for us TightVNC Server was the best working solution. Install the server on the Photoshop server and the client on another machine.

For that matter, you might need to run the VNC server as a service and enable the service option '*Allow service to interact with desktop*':
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wShhd.png

This is to get around the error '*Connection has been gracefully closed*'.